# c++ project is build successfully but gives g++ compiler error message

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, compiler-errors, g++

I have an C/C++ project.

Build Tool chain: Cross GCC

Current builder: CDT Internal Builder

**When I build my project, I got 2 error on the Problem tab:**

> Program "g++" not found in PATH   Preferences,
>   C++/Build/Settings/Discovery, [CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
>   MinGW] options
>
> Program "gcc" not found in PATH   Preferences,
>   C++/Build/Settings/Discovery, [CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
>   MinGW] options    C/C++ Scanner Discovery Problem

**On the console:** there is no error:

**Buil Cross Setting Prefix:** x86_64-pc-elf-
**Path:** build_tools\x86_64_gcc_pc_elf_4.8.1-1\bin

**x86_64-pc-elf-gcc.exe** and **x86_64-pc-elf-g++.exe** are located in that path. I don't understand the problem. It gives fake error.

I also get the same error for `rm.exe` when I try to clean.It is cleaned successfully, but it gives error. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that

- your paths configuration (in the CDT settings) has problems (some executables cannot be located)
- your actual build doesn't need these (e.g. you're just using a Makefile based project)

It appears that whenever you invoke an external tool (make, rm, ...) Eclipse is doing a sanity check on the configuration settings, just to be more userfriendly.

If you don't like the warnings, fix the missing configuration entries, or you can accept the warnings (and keep it in mind in case you start a different type of C++ project)

Comment: I solved the problem for "g++" and "gcc" by deleting error and build again. It does not appear anymore.but I have still the problem for "rm"